# Is there a name for taking the pushforward (ie pushout) over the pullback?

Tags: category-theory

Given maps continuous maps $f:U \rightarrow X$ and $g:V \rightarrow X$ between topological spaces; then there is a unique map $f \sqcup g:U \sqcup V \rightarrow X$ whose restrictions to $U$ & $V$ are the original maps ie $(f \sqcup g)|U=f$ and $(f \sqcup g)|V=g$.

This is a categorical construction; take the pullback $f':U \times_X V \rightarrow U$, $g':U \times_X V \rightarrow V$; and then the pushout over that, and writing $U \sqcup V$ for this, we have by the unique mapping property of the pushout a unique map $f \sqcup g:U \sqcup V \rightarrow X$.

This works in any category with pullbacks and pushouts.

This generalises to more than two maps, I think, by using the [wide pullback & pushout](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wide+pullback) - **Edit**: I don't think it does.

Is there a standard name for this construction - taking the pushout over the pullback?

Comment: This [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809276) might be related.

Comment: Pushforward is not a synonym of pushout, don't use it like that. In an [adhesive category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adhesive+category), you might just call this the union.

Comment: @Lin: yes, you right; still nomenclaturally its an easy mistake to make because of the duality that connects them: push vs pull; and back vs forward.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I edited the title accordingly

Comment: @magma: thanks, I forgot the title! ;).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103942/a-push-out-of-a-pull-back, where Dr. Magidin says that ``the pushout of a pullback is already a pushout''.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar:its an interesting result which I wasn't aware of; but I am asking for something slightly different - in Dr Magidins terminology in his first diagram (which is the dual of the situation I am looking at here) then $Z \rightarrow X \times_T Y$ is not neccessarily isomorphism.